# Как менять биндинг IMAGE в коде?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, изображения

Добрый день! Помогите решить задачу по программной смене биндинга `IMAGE`, никак не соображу куда копать:

`XAML`:

```
<Image x:Name="Ishodnik_Image_View"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=IshodnikVibirator_LB, Path=SelectedItem}" Source="{Binding Ssilka_Na_Ishodnik}">
```

Как это задать программно?

Comment: Решено так:
Биндинг осуществил не к контролу ListBox, а к собственной коллекции данных, листбокс юзаю только в качестве ссылки на выбранный индекс: 

Binding IshodnikViewBind = new Binding();
IshodnikViewBind.Source = ishodniki[IshodnikVibirator_LB.SelectedIndex].Ssilka_Na_Ishodnik;
Ishodnik_Image_View.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, IshodnikViewBind);

Answer (score 1):

Что-то подобное:

```
ListBox lbx = new ListBox();
TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
var binding = new Binding("SelectedValue");
binding.Source = lbx;
var bound = tbx.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```